# Getting "Time to first byte" metric from visual studio load testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, load-testing

I've setup a visual studio 2010 load testing suite to test our website.  One key metric I want is "Time to first byte" (TTFB) for each page.  Does anyone know how I can add this to the project?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Load Test Results` window expand the `Overall-->Request-->Avg. First Byte Time` and double click on `_Total` to add it in the graph.

[image]

If you want to see how to add more counters to your test, which are not added by default, check these:

1. [Specifying the Counter Sets for Computers in a Load Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404695)
2. [How to: Add Counters to Counter Sets Using the Load Test Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404704)